# Is there an elegant way to chain promises together?

Tags: javascript, promise, q, bluebird

I know that it's possible to chain promises like this:

```
somePromise
  .then(function() { return someOtherPromise; })
  .then(function() { return yetAnotherPromise; });
```

But is there a shorter way? It seems to me like this is a very common use case, so I'd expect to have a built-in mechanism like this:

```
somePromise.and(someOtherPromise).and(yetAnotherPromise);
```

Maybe I'm missing something?

(EDIT: Should have mentioned I use Bluebird with Node, which is ~Promises/A)

Comment: usually you don't return another promise, you can just return data, and then `.then` will promisify the return value if necessary.

Comment: What are `someOtherPromise` and `yetAnotherPromise` exactly? Maybe give some less-pseudo example. Are these promises actually created from actions that are executed in those callbacks?

Comment: You might be looking for `Promise.all([somePromise, someOtherPromise, yetAnotherPromise])`?

Comment: No - there is none. `.then` takes a function or ignores the argument. IN ES6 you can do `somePromise.then( () => someOtherPromise)`

Comment: @Alnitak, that's usually the case, but often it's very useful to return another promise, such as `return Promise.all([...])`

@Bergi, `Promise.all` doesn't chain promises sequentially, which is what I'm looking for. I need something like `async.waterfall` but for promises, if that make sense.

Comment: How do you obtain the other promises? This code is as parallel/sequential as `.all`

Comment: Some are created manually, some using `promisify`, some from other libraries

Comment: @lm123: OK, I only was a bit confused what you mean; because technically you cannot chain "promises", but only *functions* that return promises.

Comment: @lm123: You can shorten `.then(function(x) { return makePromise(x); })` to a simple `.then(makePromise)`, but as soon as more complicated expressions (e.g. with arguments) are involved you usually need to fall back to the function expressions. What you have already *is* quite similar to `waterfall`, except that you use `then` in between the functions instead of array delimiters.

Comment: Depending on what those more complicated expressions are, there might still be ways to get rid of the function expression, but to show you those I'd need to see actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have :

```
var promise2 = function() {
    return someOtherPromise;
};

var promise3 = function(promise2) {
    return someOtherPromise;
};
```

you van chain like that :

```
promise1
  .then(promise2) //promise 2 returns its promise
  .then(promise3); //promise3 get promise2 automatically injected as a parameter and do its job
```